# Migration testing in SharePoint application

Tags: sharepoint

I was new to SharePoint application testing. Seems I am going to do migration related testing (Manual). Can somebody advise me on how I need to approach this project and best practices associated with Migration testing in SharePoint Application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In which environment you want to do migration e.g. 2007 to 2010 , 2010 to 2013 ? You can do migration by our tool.